# Sound failed on Win7 HomePrem

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

Following [No sound on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/393287/no-sound-on-windows-7) did not solve the problem, so I ask here for help.

Moved a PC 25', OS is Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit. Now, no sound. It has an [ASRock M3A770DE motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157176) with onboard hidef and standard audio, and the standard def Envy24 Family Audio Controller WDM is the sole audio output device in Windows. It uses the VIA-IC Ensemble driver 5.12.1.3652 dated 3/15/2007 which Windows says is up to date.

Speakers work AOK when I plug my phone into them. Fail when attached to both the green jack on the back and the green jack on the front, which worked before move.

Volume mixer is not muted and volume is at max for both Device and Applications.

I also tried Logitech USB headphones; they do appear as an audio output device when attached, and although the microphone works OK, I hear no audio playback.

I’ve used multiple WAV files to test the speakers. None work. Also selected them as an audio playback device by right-clicking on the speaker icon, chose Configure, then clicked on Test (Stereo, not 5.1 Surround). No sound.

No HDMI devices attached.

Ran through http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/no-sound-help#no-sound=windows-7&v1h=win8tab1&v2h=win7tab1&v3h=winvistatab1&v4h=winxptab1 did not help.

No yellow question marks or red bangs, drivers for sound adapter up to date in Device Manager.

Windows Audio Playback Troubleshooter from Microsoft FixIt found no problem. It reported: 
Issues checked
No HDMI audio after restart Checked 
Check audio device Checked
One or more audio services are not running Checked
Audio device is disabled Checked
Low audio device  Checked
Audio device muted Checked
Audio device isn't set as default Checked
Audio playback device is unplugged Checked
Windows Update is configured to never update drivers Checked

Went into Control Panel | Sound | Playback | Speakers Properties | Advanced || and unchecked ‘Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device’, following the lead of [https://superuser.com/questions/393287/no-sound-on-windows-7](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157176) then rebooted; did not solve problem.

Where might I go from here?

[1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157176): Question 393287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by a phone call to ASRock tech support this motherboard has defective on board sound (thanks, ASRock) undocumented in their support forum, which is why there was a sound card. Removed the PCI bus sound card with a PCIe sound card, works AOK now.